# How to opt out of IE Mode for the Microsoft Edge Browser as a website author?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have deployed a web application to help my colleagues and me in our work.

As its audience was well known, I did not work to maintain compatibility with old browsers, especially not with IE11.

Now I have discovered that because my tool is deployed internally, it falls under the configured group policy for [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) - a feature of Microsoft Edge 77+ that lets enterprises configure websites to be rendered with the IE11 (Trident) Engine. The consequence of it is that my website does not work in Microsoft Edge, while it works in every other non-IE browser.

Is there a way to force usage of the Chrome engine, (similarly to all the old compatibility modes that existed in IE), without having to appeal for modification of the Enterprise Group Policy? I have skimmed the documentation pages on learn.microsoft.com, unsuccessfully.

I have full control over the HTTP content and response headers.

Comment: *A Configurable site might send a redirect response (for example, HTTP 302) with the HTTP response header "`X-InternetExplorerMode: 0`" to request that the navigation switch back to Microsoft Edge mode.* Whether this works or not depends on whether the company activated the Configurable mode, which was explicitly designed to allow both IE-reliant and modern web applications to run under the same domain. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-configurable-sites-ie-mode#switching-back-from-ie-mode-engine-to-microsoft-edge-engine

Comment: I agree with connexo's comment. But in this situation, you still need to edit the Enterprise Mode Site List to set your site having the `<open-in>Configurable</open-in>` option. This might need the person who controls Enterprise Group Policy to help to edit, you can't make it only with editing the HTTP content and response headers.